# I want in one line with bootstrap 4. But it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

My Html code (use Bootstrap4).

```
<div>
  <span class="d-inline-block">
    <i class="fa fa-file-alt fa-3x text-primary"></i>
  </span>
  <span class="d-inline-block">Kadastrinis numeris: <strong style="font-size: 22px;">8741/0002:0014</strong></span>
</div>
```

Comes out:

[image]

But need inline, example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it something like this?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- code below this line -->

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <span class="align-self-center p-2">
         <i class="fa fa-file-alt fa-3x text-primary"></i>
    </span>
  <span class="align-self-center d-inline-flex p-2 flex-column">Kadastrinis numeris: 
         <strong style="font-size: 22px;">8741/0002:0014</strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im add div class d-inline-flex this work